# Override Class Base View except one mixin

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth in my project. I can't find setting to add new user by other user. I would like to use signup procedure to add new user but I can't do it when I login. I have discover that there is view in allauth:
 class SignupView(RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, CloseableSignupMixin,
                 AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView)

I would like to override this view but except "RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin".

How to do it in right way?

Thank You and Best Regards.